# npm write access denied when trying to install netlify-lambda for stripe

Tags: npm

This happens when I was trying to install netlify-lambda in a gatsby app

```
npm install -g netlify-lambda
```

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/parser
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/types
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/generator
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/caniuse-lite
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/readable-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/duplexify
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-lambda/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread' }
npm ERR!
```

Tried but not work:

sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

sudo npm install -g netlify-lambda

reinstall npm

Answer (score 0):

You don't have root access in the Netlify build container, so sudo won't do you any good.

You also shouldn't need to `npm install` anything manually like that - you should ship your package.json in the root of your repo and it should have the specifications for your packages set.  Netlify then automatically runs `npm install`  (see [this article](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/) for more details), installs what you need, AND puts it on your $PATH so you can just run any binaries generated as a part of the installation.

This article describes the flow of our continuous deployment environment:  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/

TL;DR You should effectively be able to put `netlify-lambda` into package.json as a dependency and then run it during build with no further installation needed.